# Is it safe to store Borg backup archives without POSIX filesystem support (e.g. Windows/cloud drives)

Tags: linux, backup, filesystems

Can [Borg](https://borgbackup.readthedocs.io/) archives be safely stored on NTFS/FAT filesystems, or even a BackBlaze desktop service, without data loss? Specifically, storage without POSIX permissions, symlinks, xattrs, etc.

I read the [manual](https://borgbackup.readthedocs.io/en/stable/internals/data-structures.html#repository), and it seems nothing will break, but I need more reassurance.

Answer (score 1):

There are issues with some obscure filesystems like `vboxfs` (e.g. https://github.com/borgbackup/borg/issues/2352); however, I have been using it on plain NTFS for some while without problems. Even on `vboxfs`, although I got crashes and stale lockfiles, I didn't get any corruption (that I noticed).

Try doing a couple of backups, and test that it worked (e.g. using the very convenient `borg` FUSE filesystem). This should give you some confidence that your backups are working. (You should probably test whether your backups are working anyway).